# search through a nested dictionary and record the steps

Tags: python, python-3.x

say I have a dictionary like this:

```py
profile = {'Person':{'name':['John'], 'Description':['smart']}}
```

I am looking for a piece of code that searches for 'John', and 'Description', but doesn't know where they are in the nested dictionary. I also want to the code to print something like this:

```py
John is located in the value of profile['Person']
Description is located in the key of profile['Person']
```

How can I do that? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest some recursion with stack.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand I am very new to python. Can you explain more? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't have that much about python. Make some outer stack where you will be pushing current nested dict. Then make some function which is iterating over dict. If it sees inner dict as value - push this key to stack and make recursive call from that nested dict. I guess.

Comment: Look up how to write for loops, then nested for loops, then how to find an element in a dictionary.

Comment: How much nested is `profile` dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to [iterate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary#access-elements) through a nested dictionary. In Python Dictionary, [items()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/) method is used to return the list with all dictionary keys with values. Indexing [ ] is used to access an element of a nested dictionary

```
profile = {'Person':{'name':['John'], 'Description':['smart']},'Person1':{'name':['John1'], 'Description':['smart1']}}

for p_id, p_info in profile.items():
    for key in p_info:

        if p_info[key][0] == "John":
            print(p_info[key][0],"is located in the value of profile['",p_id,"']")
        if p_info[key][0] == "smart":
            print(p_info[key][0],"is located in the value of profile['",p_id,"']")
```

Comment: Is there also a way to search for a key? Thank you